# Is there room for improvement with questions about generating tables of incremental dates in a range for SQL Server / T-SQL?

Tags: discussion, canonical

I recently was curious about learning how to do this and googled "`tsql create table of date range`". I was greeted with

- [Get all dates between two dates in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23290454/11107541) with no version tags
- [Generate Dates between date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7824831/11107541) with [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008)
- [Generate a resultset of incrementing dates in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1478951/11107541) with [sql-server-2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005)
- [How can I generate a temporary table filled with dates in SQL Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6125504/11107541) with [sql-server-2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2000)
- [Generate date range in between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44942337/11107541with) [azure-sql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-database)

I'm sure there are more.

Also, if you search for more-localized / less-generalized expressions of the same question, you can find similar things like this (from the top few results of googling "`tsql create table of weeks site:stackoverflow.com`")

- [SQL - Create table with one column that has date by week](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35565676/11107541)
- [Creating calendar table per week using SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62840166/11107541)
- [Create table with the week numbers of the last 6 months, with their respective month and year. SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60933890/11107541)

I'm not an SME in SQL Server, so I don't have any weighty input on what to do about this. I'm not even sure if anything needs to be done here. Hence the question. Is this optimal?

Are the answers significantly different based on versions of SQL server? Is there any clear and/or non-controversial way that this could be improved to make information easier to find for non-SMEs like me? Are the variants of the question for incrementing by different special amounts like day, week, month, or year different enough to warrant their own questions?

Comment: Is what optimal? Having many questions for the same problem?  No, it's not. Are the solutions optimal? Some of them aren't no (certainly not the rCTE methods, of which some have attracted a comments on). Are there different ways to achieve this in different versions of SQL Server? Yes, though the only change of note would be support for CTE (added in 2005 if I recall correctly) and `GENERATE_SERIES` (added in 2022).

Comment: As for having varients, it often boils down to "make a calendar table" in my opinion. It honestly depends on the way the question is asked; I could probably make an answer specific for the linked questions, but then the answer would be answer specific.

Comment: Arguably, this is not a different task from "Make a tally table" or "make a query that returns a sequence of numbers" which might lead to even more duplicates, since changing a sequence of numbers to a sequence of days/weeks/something else is mostly trivial. It could certainly benefit from a good canonical that lists different approaches, but perhaps someone with more SQL server experience can chime in.

Comment: I think there are probably three main "eras" to differentiate. **<= SQL Server 2000** (No CTEs - recursive or otherwise, No `ROW_NUMBER`  to generate incrementing numbers  **>= SQL Server 2005 AND < SQL Server 2022** where answers are mostly using those things listed as unavailable in 2000.   **>= SQL Server 2022** - just use `GENERATE_SERIES`

Comment: But of course I've just looked at the 2000 tagged question and it contains answers for later versions